# Lost Clustered disk in Windows 2008 R1 SQL Cluster

Tags: windows, sql, cluster

I currently am running a 2008 R1 64 bit cluster.  Last night I get called by our first tier support that we have a failed cluster disk.  At 5PM we received the following error:

> Cluster physical disk resource 'Cluster Disk 1' cannot be brought
>   online because the associated disk could not be found. The expected
>   signature of the disk was '{f575935a-d2aa-4a6e-9345-f127ae1349cf}'. If
>   the disk was replaced or restored, in the Failover Cluster Management
>   snap-in, you can use the Repair function (in the properties sheet for
>   the disk) to repair the new or restored disk. If the disk will not be
>   replaced, delete the associated disk resource.

When I try to repair the disk I get the following error.

"No disks suitable for cluster disks were found.  For diagnostic information about the disks available to the cluster, user the Validate a configuration Wizard to run Storage Tests."

None of the services are down, none of the clustered resources other than this drive are down.

Comment: What is the status of the underlying LUN?

Answer (score 0):

Your disk is probably gone for good.

So replace the disk and start repair again.